# Странно работает перебор и удаление из списка

Tags: python

Есть функция, которая перебирает список и удаляет те значения, которые есть в другом списке.

```
geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"]

def goose_filter(birds):
    for bird in birds:
        if bird in geese:
            birds.remove(bird)
    return birds
```

Задаю значение:

```
print(goose_filter(['Pilgrim', 'pooe', 'Roman Tufted', 'Toulouse', 'African', 'gool']))
```

И выдает:

```
['pooe', 'Toulouse', 'gool']
```

Не понимаю, почему именно не было удалено 'Toulouse'. Пробовал разные варианты, список ведет себя странно и не удаляет какие-то элементы, иногда работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"]

def goose_filter(birds):
    return [x for x in birds if x not in geese]

print(goose_filter(['Pilgrim', 'pooe', 'Roman Tufted', 'Toulouse', 'African', 'gool']))

['pooe', 'gool']
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы берете за основу цикла массив, который в процессе меняете, легче всего просто создать новый список только с теми словами, которых нет в фильтре:

```
geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"]
z=[]
def goose_filter(birds,empy_list):
    for bird in birds:
        if bird in geese:
            pass
        else:
            z.append(bird)
    return z
print(goose_filter(['Pilgrim', 'pooe', 'Roman Tufted', 'Toulouse', 'African', 'gool'],z))
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Отсортировал в своем коде лист, чтобы он не менялся.
for bird in sorted(birds):

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было отсортировать список в цикле:

```
for bird in sorted(birds):
```

Или поменять местами в цикле листы:

```
for bird in geese:
    if bird in birds:
```